# How do I override a default keybinding in LightTable?

Tags: key-bindings, lighttable

The `default.keymap` has `pmeta-shift-s` bound to `:save-as` but I would like to rebind it to `:save-all`. I added the following to my `user.keymap`:

```
;; Remove the default keybinding
{:- {:editor {"pmeta-shift-s" [:save-as]}}}

;; Add my keybinding
{:+ {:app {"pmeta-shift-s" [:save-all]}}}
```

I've saved my `user.keymap` and LightTable says that it's reloaded the keymap, but pressing `pmeta-shift-s` still pops up the Save As dialog. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I'm fairly convinced this is a bug, so: https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/1180

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but ctrl modifier works:
{:+ {:app {"pmeta-ctrl-s" [:save-all]}}

It's not nearly as nice, though.  I'm used to shift.

Comment: Using `ctrl-shift-s` didn't work either. I don't think it's properly loading my user.keymap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it was not a bug, the :- and :+ keys must appear in the same map:

```
{:- {:editor {"pmeta-shift-s" [:save-as]}}

 :+ {:app {"pmeta-shift-s" [:save-all]}

     :editor {"alt-w" [:editor.watch.watch-selection]
              "alt-shift-w" [:editor.watch.unwatch]
              "f3" [:find.next]}

     :tabs {"pmeta-pagedown" [:tabs.next]
            "pmeta-pageup" [:tabs.prev]}}}}
```